# Detection script for local admin computer

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, intune

I'm newbie here and would like to ask for your help writing a powershell script and if possible to create a detection/remediation Powershell script for local admin computer.

I have created a local user administrator and password to all our computers and my objective is to create a script that will notify me when someone tries or change the password of the local admin. I tried this script below but seems not doing what I expect.

```
# This script is intended to create a custom local administrator for offline use on Entra ID joined computers.


# Define the username and password
$Username = "OfflineAdmin"

$Password = "pppppp"


# Check if the user already exists
$ExistingUser = Get-LocalUser -Name $Username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($ExistingUser) {
    "The user exists." 
    # If the user exists, update the password and set it to never expire
    Set-LocalUser -Name $Username -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force) -PasswordNeverExpires $true
} else {
    "Adding the user." 
    # If the user doesn't exist, create the local user and set the password to never expire
    New-LocalUser -Name $Username -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force) -PasswordNeverExpires
    # Then add the new user to the local administrators group
    $AdminGroup = Get-LocalGroup -Name "Administrators"
    $AdminUser = Get-LocalUser -Name $Username
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $AdminGroup -Member $AdminUser
}
Stop-Transcript

# Define the event log properties when someone change the password
$LogName = "Security"
$EventID = 4738  # Event ID for a user account was changed (password change)

# Specify the email details
$EmailFrom = "notify@email.com"
$EmailTo = "admin@admin.com"
$Subject = "Local Admin Password Change Notification"
$SMTPServer = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"

# Get the latest event from the Security log
$latestEvent = Get-WinEvent -LogName $LogName -FilterXPath "*[System[(EventID=$EventID)]]" | Select-Object -First 1

# Check if the event is not null (i.e., a password change event is found)
if ($latestEvent -ne $null) {
    # Extract relevant information from the event
    $EventTime = $latestEvent.TimeCreated
    $Username = $latestEvent.Properties[0].Value
    $ComputerName = $latestEvent.Properties[1].Value

 # Compose the email body
    $Body = "Local admin password changed on $ComputerName.`r`n`r`n"
    $Body += "Username: $Username`r`n"
    $Body += "Event Time: $EventTime`r`n"

    # Send the email
    Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer     $SMTPServer
} else {
    Write-Host "No password change events found."
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone need to change the password? They can just look at the script and get the current password in cleartext :) You might want to reconsider this approach and adopt [LAPS instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/laps/laps-scenarios-azure-active-directory)

Comment: Some of the end user has a local admin account that needs that to do some admin task on their device, but they do not have an admin rights to access our tenants. That's why I created a default admin credential so they can use that easily.  I believe when you generate a password in LAPS , it's too complicated and hassle to the end user and take note that this local admin should not expired.

Comment: @Carol Ceguerra > Implement the script from this SO answer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385476/verify-local-admin-password-change-in-powershell by Jesse burk

Comment: This might also work-[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$User = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("The AD Username to check", "Name")

$searcher=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$searcher.Filter="(&(samaccountname=$User))"
$results=$searcher.findone()
#[datetime]::fromfiletime($results.properties.pwdlastset[0])

$Set = [datetime]::fromfiletime($results.properties.pwdlastset[0])
$Expires = $Set.AddDays(30)
echo "$User's password was set $Set and will expire $Expires"

Comment: Reference- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2231693-powershell-script-to-notify-when-user-updates-password

Comment: As an aside, note that once the user has local admin rights they can clear the Event Log and you won't find any "password changed" events.